# Display ExtensionData in Grid View (ASPDNSF)

Tags: xml, aspdotnetstorefront

I am editing the Product Grid View (stock entity.gridwithprices.xml.config) and would like to test for, or display, a value from the ExtensionData4 field.
While I have success displaying/testing values of other fields (such as SKU, Name, etc.) from the Product table, the ExtensionData, ExtensionData2, etc. fields do not seem to be working in this XML template.
I have performed this task successfully with the Product pages, so I suspect the problem is tied to the XML Package, but that is where I get stuck.
Suggestions?
(working with ASPDNSF V10 Multistore)

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify aspdnsf_Getproducts stored procedure for this.